# Method property input validation

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

How should I handle the input validation of a method?
Of these two, which one is the more correct way? or there is a better way
This method is called by the constructor and $prodID can be user input or come from the db.

```
private function fill_data1($prodID)
{
    //Way 1
    filter_var($prodID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>1000000)));
    if (is_null($prodID)) {
        return FALSE;
    } elseif ($prodID === FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $prod = getArtData($prodID);
    $this->set_id($prod['artID']);
    $this->set_name($prod['artName']);
    $this->set_price($prod['precio']);
}

private function fill_data(2$prodID)
{
    //Way 2
    filter_var($prodID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>1000000)));
    if (is_null($prodID) || $prodID === FALSE)
    {
        die('invalid input for prodID (' . $prodID . '). It has to be an integer > 0');
    }
    $prod = getArtData($prodID);
    $this->set_id($prod['artID']);
    $this->set_name($prod['artName']);
    $this->set_price($prod['precio']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3: Use exceptions and put the ID validation as close to the data as possible.

```
public function getArtData($id) {
    if (!is_int($id) || $id <= 0) {
        throw new InvalidIdentifierException(
                "Article ID $id must be a valid, positive integer.");
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem with returning `false` is that you must check for the return value to handle **and** skip it. If where you handle it (the presentation layer) is several function calls removed from where it's validated (the data layer), you have to check for `false` at each level. An exception will propagate up to the first function that catches it, bypassing the remaining code in each function along the way.

```
function displayProductAction(...) {
    $prodID = $request->getParam('prod');
    $form = ...
    try {
        $form->fill_data($prodID)
        $view->form = $form;
    }
    catch (InvalidIdentifierException $e) {
        $view->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
    $view->render();
}
```

Calling `die()` causes its own difficulties. It is harder to unit test and it forces you to put the error-display code at the point of failure. What happens when you want to use your code from a web-service?

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** use `die()` when validating your input.
Your user should see a proper error message and hints on how to give a correct input.

Therefore I suggest you to use the first way.
Depending on your architecture it might make more sense to throw an exception instead of returning false.

Comment: Yes, die is a little harsh, but for sure the user will ser the message (it would be the only thing on the page)

Comment: The thing is, if the input is invalid. The execution must stop immediately, the next step can be a db write..

Comment: I hate this comment box, hitting enter submits automatically... Which would be the correct way of using an exception here?